# Background Image Opacity in CSS

Tags: opacity

How do I change my background image's opacity and just the background alone? I don't want any content on the page to change.

My CSS code:

```
html {background: url(http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs28/f/2008/131/2/7/Crumpled_white_paper_texture_by_melemel.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: If you only want to change the opacity of the background, you could simply change the opacity of the image using an image editor, it might be easier and clearer

Comment: One internet search for 'background css opacity' and I find a solution on css-tricks.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

html:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs28/f/2008/131/2/7/Crumpled_white_paper_texture_by_melemel.jpg); 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smE6N/1/)

Comment: thanks! this one worked! would you kindly explain the coding? I'm a web design newb. and I would like to understand the coding rather than just copying and pasting codes all the time.

Comment: @user3123883 There are many excelent articles about it, see: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pseudo-element-before-after/,  http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/, http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change images with css, better manipulate the picture with an editor

further you cant do that on background, because opacity only works on HTML elements like `<img>`, since its a css attribute it doesn't effect the other attributes like `background`.

so i think you have to change the entire body